# How to get the name of called method in java

Tags: java, logging, reflection

Suppose I have a method like this

```
Calculator calc;
public void testMethod(){
-----
----
Calc.add(1,2);
-----
-------
}
```

Now I want print Calculator.add at the end of the function, i.e i want to print the classname.printname at the end of the function. The printing should be generic enough that I can use the same for other methods as well. How to achieve this goal.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't quite follow, do you want to print the method you're in or the method you've just called? And should Calc start with a lower case c?

Comment: @berry the method tht ive just called

Comment: Where do you want the _printing_ to take place?  Are you trying to write to a log file?  If so, look into _Log4J_.  It's a logging library for java.

Answer (score 2):

```
private static final int CLIENT_CODE_STACK_INDEX;

static {
    // Finds out the index of "this code" in the returned stack trace - funny but it differs in JDK 1.5 and 1.6
    int i = 0;
    for (StackTraceElement ste : Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()) {
        i++;
        if (ste.getClassName().equals(Resource.class.getName())) {
            break;
        }
    }
    CLIENT_CODE_STACK_INDEX = i;
}

public static String getCurrentMethodName() {
    return Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[CLIENT_CODE_STACK_INDEX].getMethodName();
}
public static String getCallerMethodName() {
    return Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[CLIENT_CODE_STACK_INDEX+1].getMethodName();
}
```

Comment: im getting 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Array index out of range: 6
 at Reflections.getCallerMethodName(Reflections.java:32)
 at Reflections.main(Reflections.java:41)

Comment: probably because 'main' has no 'caller'

Answer (score 2):

As the very simplest approach, remember you can always call `this.getClass().getName()`:

```
class SimpleCalculator {

    public int add(int a, int b) {
        System.out.println(this.getClass().getName() +
                " - adding " + a + " and " + b);
        return a + b;
    }
}
```

---

Another common approach is to use a  logging library like [Log4J](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/log4j/index.htm).

- [Log4J API](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/)

The class you'd be using is [Logger](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/)

You configure *Log4J* to write to a certain file.

Each class declares a *Logger object* that prints messages to a file.

Each message begins with the name of the class that generated the message.

```
class SimpleCalculator {

    Logger calcLogger = Logger.getLogger(SimpleCalculator.class);

    public int add(int a, int b) {
        calcLogger.debug("add - adding " + a + " and " + b);
        return a + b;
    }
}
```

... or you could use a method like @urir suggests.

... or you could get crazy and use [AOP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming).

Comment: I cannot edit the methods im calling. I should be able to achive this goal from the method where i called the method.

Answer (score 0):

user Calculator.getClass().getName());for finding name of class and  Calculator.getMethod();

or use System.out.println( "I was called by " + e.getStackTrace()[1].getClassName() + 
                             "." +
                             e.getStackTrace()[1].getMethodName() + 
                             "()!" );

Answer (score 0):

Check below lines by changing index value:

```
 System.out.println("Name of Caller method:" 
+ new Throwable().getStackTrace()[1].getMethodName());

    System.out.println("Name of Current method:" 
+ new Throwable().getStackTrace()[0].getMethodName());
```